# Lag functions and SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

I need to get the list of users that have been offline for at least 20 min every day. Here's my data

[image: device_data]

I have this starting query but am stuck on how to sum the difference in offline_mins i.e. need to add "and sum(offline_mins)>=20" to the where clause

```
SELECT  
   userid, 
    connected,
   LAG(recordeddt) OVER(PARTITION BY userid
   ORDER BY userid, 
            recordeddt) AS offline_period,
            DATEDIFF(minute, LAG(recordeddt) OVER(PARTITION BY userid
   ORDER BY userid, 
            recordeddt),recordeddt)  offline_mins
FROM device_data where connected=0;
```

My expected results :
[image: Expected results]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your expected results.

Comment: (1) Is there always a record per user and per 5 minutes? (2) Define "every day" in "users that have been offline for at least 20 min *every day*".

Comment: everyday=24 hours . There might not be record every 5 mins ,but when the user eventually gets online there will be a record with connected=1

Answer (score 0):

This reads like a gaps-and-island problem, where you want to group together adjacent rows having the same userid and status.

As a starter, here is a query that computes the islands:

```
select userid, connected, min(recordeddt) startdt, max(lead_recordeddt) enddt,
    datediff(min(recordeddt), max(lead_recordeddt)) duration
from (
    select dd.*,
        row_number()     over(partition by userid order by recordeddt) rn1,
        row_number()     over(partition by userid, connected order by recordeddt) rn2,
        lead(recordeddt) over(partition by userid order by recordeddt) lead_recordeddt
    from device_data dd
) dd
group by userid, connected, rn1 - rn2
```

Now, say you want users that were offline for at least 20 minutes *every day*. You can breakdown the islands per day, and use a `having` clause for filtering:

```
select userid
from (
    select recordedday, userid, connected,
        datediff(min(recordeddt), max(lead_recordeddt)) duration
    from (
        select dd.*, v.*,
            row_number()     over(partition by v.recordedday, userid order by recordeddt) rn1,
            row_number()     over(partition by v.recordedday, userid, connected order by recordeddt) rn2,
            lead(recordeddt) over(partition by v.recordedday, userid order by recordeddt) lead_recordeddt
        from device_data dd
        cross apply (values (convert(date, recordeddt))) v(recordedday)
    ) dd
    group by convert(date, recordeddt), userid, connected, rn1 - rn2
) dd
group by userid
having count(distinct case when connected = 0 and duration >= 20 then recordedday end) = count(distinct recordedday)
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted this is a gaps and island problem.  This is my take on it using a simple lag function to create groups, filter out the connected rows and then work on the date ranges.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(ID int, UserID int, dt datetime, connected int)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
(1,1,'11/2/20 10:00:00',1),
(2,1,'11/2/20 10:05:00',0),
(3,1,'11/2/20 10:10:00',0),
(4,1,'11/2/20 10:15:00',0),
(5,1,'11/2/20 10:20:00',0),
(6,2,'11/2/20 10:00:00',1),
(7,2,'11/2/20 10:05:00',1),
(8,2,'11/2/20 10:10:00',0),
(9,2,'11/2/20 10:15:00',0),
(10,2,'11/2/20 10:20:00',0),
(11,2,'11/2/20 10:25:00',0),
(12,2,'11/2/20 10:30:00',0)


SELECT UserID, connected,DATEDIFF(minute,MIN(DT), MAX(DT)) OFFLINE_MINUTES 
FROM
(
    SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN connected <> LG THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY UserID,dt) grp
    FROM
    (
        select *, LAG(connected,1,connected) OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY UserID,dt) LG
        from #tmp
    ) x
) y
WHERE connected <> 1
GROUP BY UserID,grp,connected
HAVING DATEDIFF(minute,MIN(DT), MAX(DT)) >= 20
```